# How to convert this Oracle query into HSQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I am trying to convert this Oracle query into HSQL, but i have difficulties.

```
select a.t_user_id, listagg(et.event_type_name,', ') within group (order by a.t_user_id )
from t_agency a inner join t_agency_event_type aet on a.t_user_id = aet.agency_id
                inner join t_event_type et on aet.t_event_type_id=et.id
group by a.t_user_id;
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance!

**ADDED:**

My HSQL query is like this:

```
Query queryEventTypes = em.createQuery("select agency, GROUP_CONCAT(et.eventTypeName SEPARATOR ', ') as  eventTypeName " +
                        "from TAgency agency join agency.tAgencyEventTypes eat " +
                        "join eat.tEventType et " +
                        "group by hiredAgency.tUserId, hiredAgency.address, hiredAgency.city, hiredAgency.information, "
                        + "hiredAgency.website");
```

But it gives me the error:

```
unexpected token: SEPARATOR near line 1, column 46 [select agency, GROUP_CONCAT(et.eventTypeName SEPARATOR ', ') 
                    as  eventTypeName from bg.fmi.master.thesis.model.TAgency agency join agency.tAgencyEventTypes eat join eat.tEventType et 
                    group by hiredAgency.tUserId, hiredAgency.address, hiredAgency.city, hiredAgency.information, hiredAgency.website]
```

Comment: difficulties in what?

Comment: I am trying to make a hibernate query, which returns List of Object[], containing t_user_id and event_type_name (after that i think to cycle it and make a list of elements with all event_type_names. But on the 1st step it gives me errors- it does not like the grouping or it gives me a syntax error. May be i dont construct the query well and some pseudo code for this type of request will be very useful for me.

Comment: hibernate query has a different syntax and restrictions, why do you need so? May be better to use Criteria API, trying to reproduce the SQL generated by hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Try the GROUP_CONCAT function supported by HSQLDB version 2.3.x and later. The HSQLDB syntax is different and documented here.

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_aggregate_funcs

The example given in the Guide shows how you specify the grouping and ordering of the results;

```
SELECT LASTNAME, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT FIRSTNAME ORDER BY FIRSTNAME DESC SEPARATOR ' * ') FROM Customer  GROUP BY LASTNAME
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try to figure it out!

Comment: I did not manage to solve the problem by myself and i will be very thankful if you can help me.

Comment: You forgot to add the ORDER BY part before the SEPARATOR

Comment: You need the latest HSQLDB, not the older versions.